# Importing python modules in vscode vs interactive shell

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

I am just learning python. I am trying to import modules in vscode, installing them using pip. When I try to import the module it says (Pic 1) I have already satisfied the requirements but then (Pic 2/3) it says module is not found when I go to run the program in the Jupyter interactive shell. (Pic 4) However when I run the same code in the python interactive shell it works fine. This seems to be happening for all modules not just the one in this example (pyperclip). It seems like vscode/Jupyter may be looking in a different place than the python interactive shell is. However I am stuck at this point and not sure what else to try.

Thank you for you time and any help you may be able to provide.

[(Pic1) Installing module with pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Uxv.png)

[(Pic 2) Code I am trying to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwj0G.png)

[(Pic 3) Output from Jupyter shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMKe0.png)

[(Pic 4) Same code in python interactive shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI2Le.png)

Comment: Did you make sure to select the correct environment in the Python extension that you installed into? Chances are `pip install` installed into Python 2.7 but in the Python extension you selected something else (look in the status bar).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install you package using anaconda prompt, because sometimes its happen when you are using different platforms. So try `pip install pyperclip` in Anaconda prompt, hope this will solve your problem, if not then watch this [video completely](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvbUqf3Tb1s) which will give you an idea how these import error occurs and what are the solutions.